# Average no of farmers in each Town

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table name farmer data and it has attributes like farmer name, father name, pesticides used, town etc (these attributes would be required for query). also the data type of columns is var char.

I have to write a query to calculate the average no of farmers in each town.

How can I write this query? I have tried this query but its not giving me correct answer.

```
select Farmer_Name, Count(distinct town)
from farmer_data 
group by town
```

Comment: Are you using mysql or sql server? They are not the same thing.

Comment: Yes, but counting the number of distinct towns doesn't calculate an average... so it's unlikely to give you the average. Have you actually tried to solve this problem for yourself? P.S. table and column names can't have spaces unless their quoted so that query is definitely incorrect...

Comment: i have given spaces because this forum was giving me error if i use it without spaces, i have tried this query. i am using sql server.

Comment: and its not calculating average because the field data type is var char, so i was looking for some other way to solve it

Comment: If it was giving you an error about code not being formatted as code that'd be true... you can indent code by 4 spaces or highlight it and click the `()` button to mark-up code as code.

Comment: may be this was the problem.. i am just a beginner and its the first time i am asking question on some blog.

Comment: kindly ans my ques.. its urgent

Answer (score 1):

The average number of farmers is the number of farmers divided by the number of towns. Assuming each farmer only has one row in the table, you could do something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) / COUNT(DISTINCT town)
FROM   farmer_data
```

If you want the number of farmers in each town, you should use `COUNT(*)` (as you're counting the number of rows) in conjunction with a `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT   town, COUNT(*)
FROM     farmer_data
GROUP BY town
```

Comment: we need to have a result like
name of each town and the number of farmers living in that town. its not giving the write result

Comment: @user3001684 I edited my answer according to this new information, but note that what you're asking for is **not** the average.

Comment: @user3001684 Glad to help! If this indeed solves your problem, please accept the answer to indicate it.

Comment: its giving this type of output.. the output is correct but the answer of number of farmers in each town is not right, these are very huge values.
Town name    farmers
Shah Rasool   71157
Chak 60M      62486
Ch. 77 M      62663
Hootwala 62441

Comment: its format is correct but the ans of number of farmers is not correct. these are very huge values

Comment: i want no of distinct farmers in each town. may be your query counting all the farmers given in the dataset..

Comment: kindly ans my ques... its urgent